# How to replace vmdk files in a ova file

Tags: vmware, disk, esx, vmdk

I have a ova file, i want to replace a disk.vmdk from it with disk2.vmdk

How i can achieve it, what are the steps and procedure to be done like changing values of it in .mf file and .ovf file ....etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: Steps i have done:

1. Extracted the ova file, contents are [.mf, .ovf, disk1.vmdk, disk2.vmdk]
2. replace the vmdk
3. update the mf file with new sha256sum
4. updated the ovf file with new disk size
5. tarred it
6. and try deployed from vcenter

deployment fails saying Transfer Failed: ovf descriptor is not available

Comment: You should perform step 4 before updating the manifest file.

Comment: Yes my bad in framing sentences, I tried like that only but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The order should be  [.ovf, .mf,disk1.vmdk, disk2.vmdk]. Also as mentioned above by @windstorm, you have to update the .ovf file with new disk size and .mf file with new sha256sum. It worked for me